# jQuery: Get html code of links

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I want to get html links from a div without using regex.

For example:

```
<div>Please check your links to ensure they point to the correct article.For example, <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple">Apple</a> points to the article about the fruit, while <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.">Apple Inc.</a> is the title of the article about the consumer electronics manufacturer. </div>
```

I only want to copy and write.

HTML:

```
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple">Apple</a> and <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.">Apple Inc.</a>
```

---

I tried using:

```
$('div a').each(function () {
     $(this).html();
});
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: Or from the duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22499691/295783

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map it using `outerHTML` property and then `join` the array:

```
var html = $('div').children('a').map(function(){
    return this.outerHTML;
}).get().join(' and ');
```

### -jsFiddle-

For handling multiple DIVs specifically, you could use:

```
$('div:has(a)').each(function () {
    this.innerHTML = $(this).children('a').map(function () {
        return this.outerHTML;
    }).get().join(' and ')
});
```

### -jsFiddle-